# Как итеративно рендерить дерево компонентов в react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как итеративно рендерить вложенные компоненты в react? как я понял рекурсия более затратна по производительности?

Уровней вложенности может быть неограниченное количество.

Проблема в том, что при вложенности более 5 уровней, приложение забивает процессор на 100% и зависает.

Пример дерева:

```
"comments": [ { "name": "1comment", "body": "1comment", "date": "2019-05-15T15:56:15.694116Z", "id": "0179ef41-fdb6-4700-a4dc-6d7bbc54385a", "parent": null, "reply": [] }, { "name": "2comment", "body": "2comment", "date": "2019-05-17T13:59:51.167188Z", "id": "1ef06878-58b5-48b0-9349-73986ab66bb4", "parent": null, "reply": [ { "name": "2-1-comment", "body": "2-1-comment", "date": "2019-05-21T22:32:44.998207Z", "id": "514aa634-08bd-4ca3-8a1a-eb10846808ed", "parent": "5a01211d-3ee9-4bf6-9a50-462a8277898a", "reply": [ { "name": "2-1-1-comment", "body": "2-1-1-comment", "date": "2019-05-21T22:32:44.998207Z", "id": "514aa634-08bd-4ca3-8a1a-eb10846808ed", "parent": "5a01231d-3119-4bf6-9a50-462a8277898a", "reply": [] } ] } ] }, { "name": "3comment", "body": "3comment", "date": "2019-05-19T12:07:15.613266Z", "id": "5a01231d-3ee9-4bf6-9a50-462a8277898a", "parent": null, "reply": [ { "name": "3-1-comment", "body": "3-1-comment", "date": "2019-05-21T22:32:44.998207Z", "id": "514aa634-08bd-4ca3-8a1a-eb10846808ed", "parent": "5a01231d-3ee9-4bf6-9a50-462a8277198a", "reply": [] } ] } ]
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Хочу узнать можно ли в реакте итеративно (не рекурсивно) рендерить вложенные компоненты в виде дерева. пытался сделать через stack, но вложенности не получилось.

Comment: Нужно ли применять CSS стили к данному дереву? Если нет то можно воспользоваться какой-нибудь библиотекой для отрисовки объектов.

Comment: css не нужен, суть в том, что дерево очень большое и рекурсивно рендерится очень долго и вообще падает, вопрос в том, как заменить рекурсию итеративным способом, чтобы не было так затратно по ресурсам

Answer (score 0):

Не в курсах, что там с реактом, но я с подобной проблемой столкнулся при рендеринге структуры dom на js. Вот такой штуки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Алгоритм следующий:

- проходим циклом первый раз, строим корневые элементы, назначаем айди, если их нету или кривые.
- проходим циклом while, вытягивая из каждой "корневой строки" (№№ 3,5,7):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

элементы каждого следующего уровня на каждой итерации и добавляем в соответствии с айди. До тех пор пока весь проход цикла будет без единого добавления.

Все. Никакой рекурсии. Кол-во уровней вложенности определяется по кол-ву "name" в строке или скобок в конце оной. Все это и вытягивание данных по каждому уровню делается обычными строковыми ф-циями. В худшем случае с регулярками.

opd:

Сложность только в правильном вычислении элемента на опред.уровне вложенности. Можно по парности/непарности скобок, но по айди проще (айди и парент-айди).

Можно преобразовать массив и "итератить" его. Так проще должно быть.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Красным - первая итерация, зеленым - вторая, синим - третья.

Comment: вот в этом то и вопрос как заменить рекурсию итераций?)

Comment: Так а где в моем алгоритме рекурсия? Если вам будет понятней. Первый проход: выбираете комменты 1,2 и 3. (можете стазу удалять их из исходных строк) На следующем проходе комменты 2-1, 2-2, 2-3, ... 3-1,  3-2, 3-3, ... Потом 2-1-1, 2-1-2, 2-3-1 Добавил кще одну картинку в ответ.

Comment: я пытался сделать итеративно через стек и примерно так как Вы описали, но вложений может быть 5-10 уровней, т.е неограниченное количество, как отрисовать все вложения, и не просто строк а компонетов в реакт. при переборе в стек, почему то компоненты не были вложенными, а стали плоским списком, судя по Вашему решению это будет так же плоский список

Comment: Ну, так или иначе вам придется вытягивать из строк все элементы. Я не думаю, что даже при тысяче строк хоть с тысячей элементов (эта тысяча - это кол-во уровней вложенности) оно будет вешаться при обработке строк. У меня ноут 10 летней давности, так он до 100 тыс элементов со скрипом, но обрабатывает. Но основной затык именно в графической прорисовке, потом по скорости - обращение к дом, а сам парсинг готовой структуры очень быстро происходит. (но рекурсивный обход такого большого дерева ложит браузер) Возможно у вас дело не в способе обхода, а именно в прорисовке элементов.

Comment: Попробуйте просто вывести айди в виде дерева, как в проводнике виндовс - с отступами +1 таб на каждый уровень вложенности

Comment: Да, проблема именно в рендеринге, использую рекурсивный рендеринг компонентов, насколько я понял рекурсивный подход более ресурсоемкий, т.к. под локальные переменные выделяется место в памяти, в итеративном подходе, переменные обновляются. вопрос в этом и заключается как отрисовать вложенные компоненты итерацией, а не рекурсией.

Comment: Ну так отрисовуйте по одному. сначала все первые. Удаляете их из строк, потом у вас первыми в строках уже элементы 2-го уровня. Выдираете и рисуете по одному на осн. зависимостей по айди. И т.д. Но вообще, я не об этом. " использую рекурсивный рендеринг компонентов" - это 2 шага: рекурсивный перебор - раз, рендеринг полученного - два. Вот я и говорю, что может засада не в парсинге обходе, а именно в прорисовке. Выведите тупо айдишки текстом. Каждую отдельной строкой и +1 таб отступа на каждый уровень вложенности. Это даст понятие о том, что грузит.